# Switch into edit mode during for-loop

Tags: python, scripting, edit-mode

I'm iterating through a list of vertices. The for-loop is for selecting each 
vertex and translating it separately.

However whenever I switch between the modes during the for-loop the selection of the vertices behave strangely. It only selects 3 of my 6 vertices. If I uncomment the lines for switching into edit mode it works as usual.

Here is the code:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

ri = 4
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=6, radius=ri, location=(0,0,0))

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0.5)})

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
data = bpy.context.active_object.data

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

indices = np.arange(-6, 0, 1)
verts = []
for i, v in enumerate(indices):
    vert = data.vertices[v]
    verts.append(vert)


for i, v in enumerate(verts):

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    v.select = True
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, 0.5))

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
v.select = False
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Welcome to bse.  Took the liberty to edit your q (added a value for ri and removed default props from operator calls).   I'd suggest having a look into the [bmesh module](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html) to do this, as it doesn't require the flipping in and out of edit mode.  Also not sure what you are trying to achieve, reversing the verts, selecting all then translating?  Should `transform.translate` be in the for loop?